# Mule - JSON to custom Object

Tags: json, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

[image: Workflow]

```
package com.drools.demo;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.HashMap;
import com.drools.demo.cashliquidassets;

public class listasset {
    private List<cashliquidassets> cashliquidasset;

    public List<cashliquidassets> getCashliquidasset() {
        return cashliquidasset;
    }

    public void setCashliquidasset(List<cashliquidassets> cashliquidasset) {
        this.cashliquidasset = cashliquidasset;
    }

}
```

I am getting this error in the Log:

2018-06-25 18:04:13,374 [[dsProcessRules].dsprocessrule.stage1.02] ERROR org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy -

---

> Message               : Failed to transform from "json" to
>   "com.drools.demo.listasset"

```
Payload:[{
    "product": "",
    "revolving_indicator": "",
    "retirement_savings_indicator": "",
    "residual_maturity": 0.0000,
    "trading_banking_book_indicator": "",
    "provision_type": "",
    "currency": null,
    "interest_rate_type": "",
    "counterparty_resident_indicator": "AU",
    "business_date": "2017-08-13",
    "stock_index": null,
    "intra_group_counterparty": "",
    "counterparty_type": "Private_Trading_Corporation",
    "loan_held_for_sale": "",
    "collateral_type": "",
    "securitised_indicator": "",
    "parent_entity": null,
    "transaction_balance": 134.0000,
    "product_group": "Acceptances_Of_Customers",
    "entity": "AU001",
    "controlled_entity": "",
    "interest_bearing": "",
    "associate_entity": "",
    "trdgl_id": 1,
    "housing_loan_classification": "",
    "loan_type": "",
    "issuer_type": null,
    "transaction_currency": "AUD",
    "issuer": null,
    "related_entity": null,
    "related_indicator": "",
    "counterparty_code": "CP001",
    "security_class": null,
    "asset_liability_indicator": "A"
}, {
    "product": "",
    "revolving_indicator": "",
    "retirement_savings_indicator": "",
    "residual_maturity": 0.0000,
    "trading_banking_book_indicator": "",
    "provision_type": "",
    "currency": null,
    "interest_rate_type": "",
    "counterparty_resident_indicator": "AU",
    "business_date": "2017-08-13",
    "stock_index": null,
    "intra_group_counterparty": "",
    "counterparty_type": "Private_Trading_Corporation",
    "loan_held_for_sale": "",
    "collateral_type": "",
    "securitised_indicator": "",
    "parent_entity": null,
    "transaction_balance": 1.0000,
    "product_group": "Acceptances_Of_Customers",
    "entity": "AU001",
    "controlled_entity": "",
    "interest_bearing": "",
    "associate_entity": "",
    "trdgl_id": 2,
    "housing_loan_classification": "",
    "loan_type": "",
    "issuer_type": null,
    "transaction_currency": "USD",
    "issuer": null,
    "related_entity": null,
    "related_indicator": "",
    "counterparty_code": "CP002",
    "security_class": null,
    "asset_liability_indicator": "A"
}, {
    "product": "Deposit_At_Call",
    "revolving_indicator": "",
    "retirement_savings_indicator": "",
    "residual_maturity": 0.0000,
    "trading_banking_book_indicator": "",
    "provision_type": "",
    "currency": null,
    "interest_rate_type": "",
    "counterparty_resident_indicator": "AU",
    "business_date": "2017-08-13",
    "stock_index": null,
    "intra_group_counterparty": "",
    "counterparty_type": "",
    "loan_held_for_sale": "",
    "collateral_type": "",
    "securitised_indicator": "",
    "parent_entity": null,
    "transaction_balance": 658.0000,
    "product_group": "",
    "entity": "AU001",
    "controlled_entity": "",
    "interest_bearing": "",
    "associate_entity": "",
    "trdgl_id": 3,
    "housing_loan_classification": "",
    "loan_type": "",
    "issuer_type": null,
    "transaction_currency": "AUD",
    "issuer": null,
    "related_entity": null,
    "related_indicator": "",
    "counterparty_code": "CP00686",
    "security_class": null,
    "asset_liability_indicator": "A"
}]

  Transformer: 
     JsonToObject{
                this=655203e3,
                name='JsonToListasset', 
                ignoreBadInput=false, 
              returnClass=SimpleDataType{
  type=com.drools.demo.listasset, 
  mimeType='application/json', 
  encoding='null'}, 

sourceTypes = [SimpleDataType {
            type = java.io.Reader, mimeType = '*/*', encoding = 'null'
        }, SimpleDataType {
            type = java.net.URL, mimeType = '*/*', encoding = 'null'
        }, SimpleDataType {
            type = java.io.File, mimeType = '*/*', encoding = 'null'
        }, SimpleDataType {
            type = java.lang.String, mimeType = '*/*', encoding = 'null'
        }, SimpleDataType {
            type = java.io.InputStream, mimeType = '*/*', encoding = 'null'
        }, SimpleDataType {
            type = [B, mimeType = '*/*', encoding = 'null'
            }]

 }
```

> Payload Type          : java.lang.String

Element               : /dsprocessrule/processors/2 @ dsProcessRules:dsprocessrules.xml:40 (JSON to Object)

Element XML           :

---

> Root Exception stack trace:
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize
>   instance of com.drools.demo.listasset out of START_ARRAY token

at [Source: java.io.StringReader@69dbfc64; line: 1, column: 1]

Any suggestion. Stuck for twodays.

Thank you
Bhaskar

Comment: What Mule Runtime version are you using? Are you using the communitiy edition or the enterprise edition? I would suggest to use DataWeave instead, if it is possible.

Comment: I am using Mule Runtime 3.9.0.  Using CE 3.9.0 tried on EE 3.9.0 runtime to same issue.  I am new to Mule. Can you suggest the Dataweave code ?

Comment: Could you please also  share your flow XML? I would also suggest to take part in the free trainings of the MuleSoft.U: https://training.mulesoft.com/ There are hours of video resources available about DataWeave. It plays already an important role in Mule Runtime 3.9 but it is going to be even more important starting from Mule 4.

Comment: there is no xml. I read data from database. convert the resultset to json. json to object is my issue.

Comment: By flow XML I mean the XML representation of the flow, that you have already copied in the question as a screenshot. It could help, if you would share the XML representation of your mule flow. Then it would be more obvious what you want to achieve.

Comment: Solution :  Able to resolve it by add @JsonProperty property to all fields in the getsetter file.